# Fate (or Fudge) by e-mail

Tags: fate, play-by-post, fudge

Are there any rules adaptations out there for Fate (any variation, including Fudge) by e-mail?  Or has anyone played by e-mail with any house rules?

I'm looking to run a pbem, and wanted to adapt the Fate rules, but I wanted to check to see if there were any adaptations out there before I started.

Comment: No matter how you do it, it's going to be very slow. Fate is a very social game, and email simply can't capture a lot of those aspects (no pun intended).

Comment: There are ways around that.  I already have ideas.  When you deal with pbp from my experience, you have to change paradigm, and you can't do the same things that you do ftf.  Or you end up with something that's slow and unsatisfying.

Comment: That's true. Emailing compels is going to be... tricky, though. I can think of a couple ways around it, but they all take time. (Should move to chat if the discussion continues)

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on a system for play-by-post for Fate. It basically uses Fate as the "back-end" (mechanics that the GM uses), but to the players it is basically like a choose-your-own adventure game.

So the GM sends the player a list of choices or actions, the player chooses one of them (or makes up his own action), and then the GM adjudicates the action. The player does not maintain a list of skills or aspects; those are all kept by the GM and updated as the narrative evolves.

Comment: That doesn't really sound like Fate, because it takes a lot of the player's ability to affect the narrative away.  But thanks for the suggestion!